# What might be wrong, ls doesn't work on my own shell

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have to write my own shell, and it's almost complete but I have a problem with ls/pwd

ls is giving me this error: cannot access'': No such file or directory

pwd is working in some way, but still it is giving me error:ignoring non-option arguments

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IpRd.png
What might be the problem?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
void  parsowanie(char *line, char **argv)
{
    while (*line != '\0') {
        while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\n'|| *line == '\t' )

            *line++ = '\0';
            *argv++ = line;

        while (*line != '\0' && *line!= ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n')
            line++;
    }
    *argv = '\0';
}
int main()
{

    printf("MicroShell\nAutor:Amadeusz Lewandowski\n");
    char co_chcesz[500],cwd[500],login[50],*argv[1000],*to;
    memset(argv,0,999);
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    while(strcmp(co_chcesz,"exit\n"))
        {
        sleep(1);
        getcwd(cwd,sizeof(cwd));
        getlogin_r(login,sizeof(login));
        printf("[%s:%s]\n$ ",login,cwd);
        fgets(co_chcesz,1000,stdin);
        if (strcmp(co_chcesz,"help\n")==0)
            {
            printf("autor to miranda orange\n");
            continue;
            }
        pid=fork();

        if(pid==0)
        {
            if (execvp(*argv,argv)<0)
            {
                perror("The following error occurred");
                printf("Value of errno:%d\n",errno);
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
            waitpid(pid,&status,0);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please put the output as text into the question and not as an image or a link to an external image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: $ ls
ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory
$ pwd
pwd: ignoring non-option arguments
Thanks! A friend told me that the last [] of argv should be NULL for this to work, but even when I force it, this doesn't work

Comment: Please put the output in the question and not in comments. And is this really your full code? `parsowanie` is never called and `argv` is never actually set.

Comment: That is just for my exam, and the deadline is for tomorrow, a lot of people are looking for the code here now. I just don't want them to copy it. Anyway, I solved the problem by just putting there a loop that replaces empty space with null :D

Comment: `waitpid` only makes sense when `pid != 0` (This is unrelated to your problem)

Comment: If `execvp` fails, you should call `_exit`. (Also unrelated to your problem)

Answer (score 0):

Your command-line splitting function is wrong. Reformatted here to better show how it was implemented:

```
void  parsowanie(char *line, char **argv)
{
    while (*line != '\0') {
        /* Eating whitespace */
        while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\n'|| *line == '\t' )
            *line++ = '\0';

        /* Adding next command line argument to `argv` */
        *argv++ = line;

        while (*line != '\0' && *line!= ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n')
            line++;
    }
    *argv = '\0';
}
```

The problem is that you add the next command line argument to `argv` before you actually know if there *is* a next command line argument.  So we have to add a test before `*argv++ = line;`. The test in the `while` statement now becomes unnecessary.

```
void  parsowanie(char *line, char **argv)
{
    while (1) {
        /* Eating whitespace */
        while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\n'|| *line == '\t' )
            *line++ = '\0';

        /* Checking if there are more command line arguments */
        if (!*line)
          {
            /* Terminating `argv` */
            *argv = NULL;
            return;
          }

        /* Adding next command line argument to `argv` */
        *argv++ = line;

        while (*line != '\0' && *line!= ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n')
            line++;
    }
}
```